# C++: Deep Copy Diamond Pointer Structure

Tags: c++

In my simulation software, I generate objects with pybind11. So all objects are stored in std::shared_ptr with a not known structure at compile time. For parallelisation of my simulation I need to run the same configuration with different seeds. I want to implement the duplication of these objects in one call on the C++ side.

Following a minimal example, where
I want **a2** to be a deepcopy of **a**, with the diamond structure.

```
// Type your code here, or load an example.
#include <memory>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

class C{};
class B{
    public:
    B(std::shared_ptr<C> c):c(c){}
    std::shared_ptr<C> c;
};
class A{
    public:
    A(std::shared_ptr<B> b1, std::shared_ptr<B> b2):b1(b1), b2(b2){}
    std::shared_ptr<B> b1;
    std::shared_ptr<B> b2;
};

auto init(){
    auto c = std::make_shared<C>();
    auto b1 = std::make_shared<B>(c);
    auto b2 = std::make_shared<B>(c);
    auto a = std::make_shared<A>(b1,b2);
    return a;
}


int main(){
    auto a = init();
    auto a2 = a; //deepcopy of a, where b1 and b2 of the copy point to the same object C
}
```

The only solution I came up with is passing a map<pointer,shared_ptr>. This allows for lookup if the shared_ptr has already been deep copied. (Here I have some problems with the typing as I need to dynamicly cast back the types. This feels really ugly and bugprone.)

Comment: there is no inheritance in your code, nor a diamond

Comment: I was refering to the pointer structure/ownership not to the diamond-problem. A owns two Bs who own the same C. This gives a a diamond shape.

Comment: Why not write a `clone` method in `A` that just does a similar thing as your `init` function?

Comment: you can write a copy constructor that checks if the pointees are the same and if they are makes only a single deep copy.

Comment: At compile time I don't know, the exact structure, as it is generated in python. Right now I do exactly this on the python side. But this has caused bugs in the past, with misconfiguration. And I was looking to get a stable solution for this problem.

Comment: `a` in main is a `std::shared_ptr<A>`. Do you want `a2` to be a `std::shared_ptr<A>` pointing to a separate `A`?

Comment: @Caleth Yes exactly.

Comment: why not `auto a2 = init();` ? If the answer is "no because `init` internally uses the seed" then pass the seed to `init`. I am afraid the code you posted does not illustrate your actual issue

Comment: You said this is configuration. Shouldn't it be all const? Then you don't need any deep copy. If the seed is part of the configuration consider writing a method to change a setting that creates a shallow copy with just the seed changed. If the seed is in `C` you end up with a deep copy again though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `std::shared_ptr<void>` to type-erase all your shared pointers, using [`std::static_pointer_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast) to go to and from your actual types.

```
using Seen = std::set<std::shared_ptr<void>>;

template <typename T>
std::shared_ptr<T> deep_copy(std::shared_ptr<T> source, Seen & seen) {
    if (auto it = seen.find(std::static_pointer_cast<void>(source)); it != seen.end()) {
        return std::static_pointer_cast<T>(*it);
    }
    auto dest = make(*source, seen);
    seen.insert(std::static_pointer_cast<void>(dest));
    return dest;
}
```

You can then either write constructors that take an existing instance and a `seen` map to deep copy the members, allowing them to be private.

```
template <typename T>
std::shared_ptr<T> make(const T & source, Seen & seen) {
    return std::make_shared<T>(source, seen);
}    

class C{
    public:
    C(){}
    C(const C &, Seen &){}    
};    
class B{
    std::shared_ptr<C> c;
    public:
    B(std::shared_ptr<C> c):c(c){}
    B(const B & other, Seen & seen):c(deep_copy(other.c, seen)){}
};
class A{
    std::shared_ptr<B> b1;
    std::shared_ptr<B> b2;
    public:
    A(std::shared_ptr<B> b1, std::shared_ptr<B> b2):b1(b1), b2(b2){}
    A(const A & other, Seen & seen):b1(deep_copy(other.b1, seen)), b2(deep_copy(other.b2, seen)){}
};

int main(){
    auto a = init();
    Seen a2_seen;
    auto a2 = deep_copy(a, a2_seen);
}
```

Or you can have overloads of `make` for each type, where `make<T>` would need to be friended by `T` if the members were private.

```
std::shared_ptr<C> make(const C &, Seen &) {
    return std::make_shared<C>();
}

std::shared_ptr<B> make(const B & other, Seen & seen) {
    auto c = deep_copy(other.c, seen);
    return std::make_shared<B>(c);
}

std::shared_ptr<A> make(const A & other, Seen & seen) {
    auto b1 = deep_copy(other.b1, seen);
    auto b2 = deep_copy(other.b2, seen);
    return std::make_shared<A>(b1, b2);
}
```